# Dynamically add accordion elements to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically add accordion elements to my DOM and I cannot seem to add it correctly so that the new element will have it's ID in place, class in place etc...

Here is my code:

```
function addAccordion(esr){

var elementID = document.getElementById("ThreatMainDiv_" + esr.marking);
var emittersDiv = document.getElementById("Emitters");

if(elementID != null){
    return;
}

    var marking = esr.marking;
    var tmp;
    tmp = "\"" + "ThreatMainDiv_" + marking + "\"";
    var topDiv = '<div id='+ tmp + ' class="accordionTitle"><h1 style="font-size: 16px"></h1></div>';
    var tDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tDiv.innerHTML = topDiv;
    $('#Emitters').append(tDiv);
};
```

How can I add it correctly?

Comment: What is meaning of accordion element?

Comment: What isn't working? I've guessed at the rest of your code (as you haven't provided a full example) but it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/y5fhrv93/1/

Comment: drop down element like in the link :

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qunujezeni/edit?html,js,output

Comment: lets make it more simple, how can I create "offline strings" that later on will be added to my DOM and that Their attributes will be in place?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('.accordionTitle').click(function(){});
```

with

```
$(document).on('click','.accordionTitle',function(){});
```